# Compute $P(2\leq x\leq 8)$ with Poisson distribution and $\lambda=7.2$

Tags: r, probability, self-study

Compute $P(2\leq x\leq 8)$ with Poisson distribution and $\lambda=7.2$

My attempt:

I need calculate this using $R$. then

I use this:

```
> ppois(8,7.2, lower.tail = FALSE) - ppois(2,7.2,lower.tail = TRUE)
```

Is correct this? I'm a little confused here.

Other question: I need calculate 75 percentil of this distribution but i don't have idea of how solve this. Can someone help me?

In this case i think could be using qpois command but i don't sure.

Comment: A lower-case $x$ is typically used to represent a realized value of a random variable $X$.  Did you in fact mean to calculate $P(2\le 8X)$?  You also said you need to calculate the 75th percentile of the distribution.  Is that in addition to $P(2\le 8X)$?  Also, what is $X$?  Is it distributed as a poisson with $\lambda =7.2$?

Also, please add the self-study tag.

Comment: oh sorry, i made a mistake!!! @StatsStudent i edited that. yes $X$ is distributed as a poisson with $\lambda=7.2$ and the other question is addition to that!

Comment: Hint for calculating $P(2\le X \le 8) $:  Write out the Probability Mass Function of a Poisson Distribution with $\ \lambda$ = $7.2$  Then calculate by hand $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$.  This should give you $P(X\le 2)$.  Then compare your answer to the one R would gives until you are certain you have the right R function (additional hint:  look at dpois, ppois, and qpois in the R help documentation).  You should then be able to figure out how to calculate $P(X \le 8)$ similarly and the final answer by subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is not correct:** Your inequality is *inclusive* of $X=2$ so you should not subtract the probability of this value in your calculation.  You can calculate the desired probability either by generating each of the individual mass-function values and summing them:

```
POIS <- dpois(2:8, lambda = 7.2)
PROB <- sum(POIS);
PROB;

[1] 0.6965463
```

or by taking the different of the cumulative distribution value, but removing the values *below* $X=2$:

```
PROB <- ppois(8, lambda = 7.2) - ppois(1, lambda = 7.2);
PROB;

[1] 0.6965463
```

Comment: Ben,  this is a self-study question.  In general you shouldn't be giving the answers to students, but allow them some time to solve them and think through them with hints.

Comment: Oops - answered too quickly and didn't realise it was self-study (thought it was just a coding problem).  Since this has now been accepted I can't delete, so I guess we're stuck with it!

Comment: No worries.  Been there.  Done that.  Just a friendly reminder.